# bootstrap carousel image which is display none div taking space

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I have bootstrap carousel and carousel of img has `data-mobil` and `data-table` attribute and when I resize the window for tablet my img src value's has been chancing with `data-table` src or when I resize the window for mobile my img src has been chancing width `data-mobil` src..it's okey so far..but at the same thime if `data-mobil` or `data-tablet` is undefined I mean is empty than make it display:none; but my display none take space why ?

[click to see live example](http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/stackoverflow/anasayfa.html) - resize window for tablet version

```js
function makeResize() {
  var imageSrc = $(".main-carousel img");
  if ($(window).width() <= 768 && $(window).width() > 480) {
    $(imageSrc).each(function(key, value) {
      if ($(value).data('tablet') == undefined)
        $(value).parent(".item").hide();
      
      else {
        $(value).attr('src', $(value).data('tablet'));
        $(value).parent(".item").show();
      }
    });
  } else if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
    $(imageSrc).each(function(key, value) {
      if ($(value).data('mobil') == undefined) {
        $(value).parent(".item").hide();
      } else {
        $(value).attr('src', $(value).data('mobil'));
        $(value).parent(".item").show();
      }
    });
  } else {
    $(imageSrc).each(function(key, value) {
      $(value).attr('src', $(value).data('src'));
      $(value).show();
    });
  }
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  
   $(window).resize(function(){
        makeResize();
    });
    makeResize();
});
```

```css
.main-carousel{
  width:1000px;
}
.main-carousel img{
  width:100%;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" /><link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

</head>
<body>
  
   <div id="homepage-carousel" class="carousel carousel-fade slide main-carousel" data-ride="carousel">
     
        <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#homepage-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#homepage-carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#homepage-carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
  </ol>

            <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
            

              <div class="item active">
                <img src="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/normal/2017-02/banner_Hn3kjP6eM7ltkZzATMMkanitur-enguzel-anilar-manset-banner-2017-6subat.jpg"  data-mobil="http://www.anitur.com.tr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Karadeniz24-372x221.jpg">
              </div>

              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/normal/2016-12/banner_r7SIBGm1BaKCNMsZojfNtermal-bolgeler.jpg"  data-tablet="http://www.anitur.com.tr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Silversea-cruise-1024x657.jpg" data-mobil="http://www.anitur.com.tr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Karadeniz24-372x221.jpg">
              </div>
              <div class="item">
                <img src="http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/resimler/normal/2017-01/banner_PYo0aKYQiz6VN3XF1rTGunknown-2.jpeg"  data-tablet="http://www.anitur.com.tr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/Silversea-cruise-1024x657.jpg" data-mobil="http://www.anitur.com.tr/blog/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/Karadeniz24-372x221.jpg">
              </div>


            </div>
        </div>
  
  
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: i believe the issue is there since carousel check for all div.item  element and add/remove class active. When ever  the active class is applied on the display none div you are seeing a grey out div on your screen.

Comment: is there any function for add/remove like hide/show ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with below code. I have tested it in the local setup.

Hope this helps.

```
  function makeResize() {
  var imageSrc = $(".main-carousel img");
  if ($(window).width() <= 768 && $(window).width() > 480) {
    $(imageSrc).each(function(key, value) {
      if ($(value).data('tablet') == undefined)

         if($(value).parent("div").hasClass("active"))
         {
          $(value).parent("div").removeClass("item active").css('display','none');
          $(value).parent("div").next("div").addClass("active");
         }
         else
         {
          $(value).parent("div").removeClass("item active").css('display','none');
         }

      else {
        $(value).attr('src', $(value).data('tablet'));
        $(value).parent("div").addClass("item").css('display','');
      }
    });
  } else if ($(window).width() <= 480) {
    $(imageSrc).each(function(key, value) {
      if ($(value).data('mobil') == undefined) {

         if($(value).parent("div").hasClass("active"))
         {
          $(value).parent("div").removeClass("item active").css('display','none');
          $(value).parent("div").next("div").addClass("active");
         }
         else
         {
          $(value).parent("div").removeClass("item active").css('display','none');
         }
      } else {
        $(value).attr('src', $(value).data('mobil'));
        $(value).parent("div").addClass("item").css('display','');
      }
    });
  } else {
    $(imageSrc).each(function(key, value) {
      $(value).attr('src', $(value).data('src'));
       $(value).parent("div").addClass("item").css('display','');
      $(value).show();
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: it's interesting as before nothing change I guess there is something with carousel not with div or img

Comment: @recruit_man is there any link where i can check the full updated code of yours?

Comment: if possible create a code pen because the above code is not working exactly as its behaving in your web page. May be some media query or additional js are there

Comment: it's some big project that is why I uploaded for you http://cdn.anitur.com.tr/download/for_deep.rar (index.html)

Comment: I tried add codepen and I added but its'n work as expect like current

Answer (score 1):

You're hiding the item, but it still exists as far as the slider is concerned, that's why you're seeing a blank spot for it.  You need to either `.remove()` it or if you need to bring it back later use `.detach()`

https://api.jquery.com/detach/

```
if ($(value).data('tablet') == undefined) {
  var hidden = $(value).parent(".item").detach()
}
```

and then in the code block where you want it brought back

```
if (hidden) {
  hidden.appendTo('target you want it added to')
}
```

Comment: first I will $(value).parent(".item").remove(); but for bring it how detach must be using ?

Comment: hi I'm using these codes:
http://codepen.io/cowardguy/pen/VPdgzR
but I guess it work's and there is no any detach() function is it true right ? and thank you so much